What is a good way to keep the SQL queries in a Rust application that uses sqlx?
At the moment I have my SQL queries as a multiline string in my Rust files.
        let sql = r#"
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                public.users
            WHERE
                "email" = $1
        "#;

        let user = match sqlx::query_as::<Postgres, User>(sql)...

Due to indentation the queries have a lot of whitespaces in them.
Is this a problem? having all this extra whitespace sent to the SQL server over and over again?
Is there any better way of keeping the SQL? or some SQL builder that would allow to have the code nice and will generate the SQL more compact and without all those extra whitespaces?

Iirc there was some performance issues with sqlx, not sure if they fixed it. Personally, I dont like having to open a db connection when compiling so I use cornucopia

If you want to keep multiline string literals in your Rust code while avoiding the extra indentation in the string data, you can use the indoc crate as mentioned here.

I went with indoc. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! If you can post it as an answer I can accept it.
